# Cherokee port rewrite urls from .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cherokee

I am tryging to port my htaccess rewrite rules to Cherokee. I already tried [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/118208/how-to-port-apache-rewrite-rules-to-cherokee). This works for me, but I can't seem to get the rule I am using working.

The apache rule:

```
RewriteRule ^dealinfo/(.*)/(.*) redirect.php?url=dealinfo/$1/$2
```

What it needs to do is redirect a user when they click on domain.com/dealinfo/1234/random-title to redirect.php server side. For this I need an internal redirect.

Whenever I try to add this redirect or some variations I either get a 500 server error or it's just not working (404).

Comment: in cherokee, are you setting it as an internal or external redirection?
what version of cherokee?
is the php handling rule at the top of the list and non-final? (i apologize for the answer; i don't have enough rep yet for a comment)